# Column is not autoincrementing in mysql

Tags: mysql

When I insert a new row the `treeId` column is always 1.
The `treeId` column is not included in the insert statement.

What could be causing it to not increment?

My table code is

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `parentUuid` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `treePath` text,
  `treeId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `state` enum('subscribed','registered','banned') NOT NULL,
  `dobMonth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dobYear` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateSubscribed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateRegistered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('unspecified','male','female') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unspecified',
  `dd` float DEFAULT '0',
  `mainRegion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`,`treeId`),
  KEY `parentid` (`parentUuid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Works for me using your table, post your insert statement

Comment: Works for me too: `INSERT INTO users (uuid, parentUuid, treePath, firstName, lastName, email,salt, password, state, dobMonth, dobYear, dateSubscribed, dateRegistered, gender, dd, mainRegion) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'subscribed', 5, 1973, '2011-05-01', '2011-05-02', 'male', 1, 2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer ([Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html))

> For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a
>   secondary column in a multiple-column index.   In this case, the
>   generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as
>   `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`.   This is
>   useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
Which returns:

+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
```

So because I had a joint key on `uuid` (which is always unique) and on treeId (which is the auto-increment) then it was creating a new increment group each time.

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to auto-increment don't specify the treeId field in your insert.